# Gauge Failed to start gauge API: Error occurred while waiting for runner process to finish

Tags: java, gauge

I'm quite new to gauge and have problems running a set of gauge tests. When I try to **gauge run** I get the following console output:

```
src\main\java\de\...\qa\Common.java:3: error: package com.github.....gauge.graphql does not exist
import com.github.....gauge.graphql.GraphqlSetup;
^
symbol:   class VariableStorage
location: class Pricing
src\main\java\de\...\qa\testcraft\GaugeTestCraft.java:3: error: package com.github.....gauge.random.data does not exist
import com.github.....gauge.random.data.VariableStorage;
^
src\main\java\de\...\qa\testcraft\TestCraftExecutor.java:4: error: package org.tinylog does not exist
import org.tinylog.Logger;
^
src\test\java\de\...\qa\PricingTest.java:8: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
^
src\test\java\de\...\qa\PricingTest.java:9: error: package org.yaml.snakeyaml does not exist
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
^
src\test\java\de\...\qa\TestVariableStorage.java:3: error: package com.github.....gauge.random.data does not exist
import com.github.....gauge.random.data.VariableStorage;
^
src\test\java\de\...\qa\TestVariableStorage.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public class TestVariableStorage implements VariableStorage {
^
symbol: class VariableStorage
src\test\java\de\...\qa\PricingTest.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
@Test
^
symbol:   class Test
location: class PricingTest
src\test\java\de\...\qa\PricingTest.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
@Test
^
symbol:   variable Logger
location: class TestCraftExecutor
src\test\java\de\...\qa\TestVariableStorage.java:12: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
src\test\java\de\...\qa\TestVariableStorage.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
src\test\java\de\...\qa\TestVariableStorage.java:22: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
55 errors
Error occurred while waiting for runner process to finish.
Error : exit status 1
Error ----------------------------------

[Gauge]
Failed to start gauge API: Error occurred while waiting for runner process to finish.
Error : exit status 1

Get Support ----------------------------
        Docs:          https://docs.gauge.org
        Bugs:          https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues
        Chat:          https://spectrum.chat/gauge

Your Environment Information -----------
        windows, 1.1.1, 6e0d83f
        html-report (4.0.12), java (0.7.9), python (0.3.11), screenshot (0.0.1), xml-report (0.2.3)
```

Does someone know how this happens and how to solve it? Here are some additional informations:

- Java version:14.0.2
- Gauge version: 1.1.1
- Maven version: 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve the problem.
You should check your project's **gauge.log**. The **Traceback** is in the file, that will help you.
Don`t see the output, it will not work.